# Find sea ice concnetration for lat, lon and time values of a large dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

The sea ice concentration (sic) data I downloaded has latitude and longitude given in terms of xc (x coordinates of projection (eastings)) and yc (y coordinate of projection (northings)). Hence lat and lon are 2D. What is the quickest/most efficient way to get the sic values of a large df of lat, lon and datetime, given this xarray.

Sea ice concentration daily gridded data can downloaded from Copernicus: https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/satellite-sea-ice-concentration?tab=overview

my attempt is as follows:

initialise data set with lat, long and time (however, in reality we are looking at v. large dfs)

```
df_trajs = pd.DataFrame({
    'latitude': [51.5074, 40.7128, 37.7749],
    'longitude': [0.1278, 74.0060, 122.4194],
    'datetime': ['2022-01-01 12:00:00', '2022-01-02 12:00:00', '2022-01-03 12:00:00']
})

df_trajs['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_trajs['datetime'])
```

#actual code

```
def function_find_var_on_Lambert_Azimuthal_Grid(lat, lon, datetime):    
    dataset = xarray_of_ice_data     
    dataset = dataset.sel(time = datetime, method='nearest') #select the right time
    var='ice_conc' #variable  
    idxs = (np.abs(ds.lon - lon) + np.abs(ds.lat - lat)).argmin(dim = ["xc", "yc"])   #find indices
    value = dataset[var].isel(idxs).values    
    lat_in_ds = ds.lat.isel(idxs).values
    lon_in_ds = ds.lon.isel(idxs).values
    return value

def append_sic_col(df_trajs):
    df_trajs = df_trajs.copy()
    df_trajs.loc[:, 'sic'] = df_trajs[['latitude', 'longitude', 'datetime']].apply(lambda x: function_find_var_on_Lambert_Azimuthal_Grid(*x), axis=1)
    return df_trajs

df_trajs = append_sic_col(df_trajs)
```

Comment: Hi, can you please post an example of the input data you have? Do you have a `nc` file that you open with `xarray` and then somehow convert to pandas?